# adding .dll file to visual studio, and open in the code

Tags: visual-studio, dll, f#

Hi I currently have a uni course in f#, where i need to use a .dll file that my professor made, in my code. In this picture, the parser.dll file has a red circle around it, and the current f# file has a blue:

[image]

Now the parser.dll is a parser that i need to pass some strings to, and get some output in my f# program.
My professor is for some reason able to acces this file by simply putting the parser.dll file in the current directory. When i do this in visual studio, the .dll file is hidden in the file explorer, and i am not ablue to acces it in the code either.

Now i could read some places that it could be a good idea to create references to it in the solution explorer>add>Reference>Browse, and try to find it on my machine (tried a few different locations), it is still hidden to me in the browse tool.

What is the best thing for me to do? and why is my dll file hidden from me when I attempt to add it using the "browse feature"?

Thank you

Comment: You need to have a project file (`fsproj`) if you want to reference libraries, or you can use a script file (`fsx`) instead of a regular `fs` source code. Your professor is probably using a project file - you should be able to get this from them.